# how to perform cosine similarity based semantic search in elastic search query on a text field?

Tags: elasticsearch, nlp, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

I am performing  a match on a text field(skills). I don't want a exact match , instead i want cosine similarity based search on the field.

```
GET 2/_search
{
  "_source": ["Skills"], 
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "Job_Group": "sales"
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        
        {
          "filter": {
            "match":{
              "Skills":"Designation"
            }
          },
          "weight": 15
        }
      ]
    }
    }
}
```

The above query is for exact match. How do i include some sort of semantic search(Cosine similarity based in the query on skills field). The skills field is a free text field, so i want matching to happen based on their semantic meaning also. Example--- skills -Communication & talking should reflect some sort of similarity and boost the score.

Comment: I feel like I don’t have enough info based on your question, but It seems to me that you need some sort of additional pre-processing step. For example, you extract the “skills” match, get the cosine similarity score, and add the corresponding logic. But also, I see that you have “weight” there, not sure how that weight is calculated

Comment: weight is not calculated, we can assign it manually.Weight is basically the weight we want to add to final score, in case skills field matches "designation". Now, if we have "Design" in skills field, there should be some sort of similarity (like 0.6 on scale of 0 to 1), and that score should be added to final score, based on what manual weight we have given.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple- Elastic is wrapping [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/), and Lucene has More-Like-This which implement TF-IDF (BM25 to be more precise) and some additional wisdom. Try it, it will give you good similarity results. [Explanation](https://www.slideshare.net/SeaseLtd/how-the-lucene-more-like-this-works) can be found in this link and various others.